# Improve Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been trying to improve the Firestore rules that secure the database for a few days now. I only seems to lock everyone out with every edit. The rules I use now are the basic rules found in the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview). Which are:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like to extend the security a bit to tighten up the edit rules. My database looks like this:

```
Users (collection) > User (document) > User specific data
```

What I would like to have is that every authenticated user can read all the data, but only the user a document belongs to (by unique user id) may edit/add/delete their data.

I hope one of you could point me in the right direction, as I seem to not get any wiser from the official documentation.

Update: How I integrated Firestore in my Android app.

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users");

CollectionReference colRef = db.document(user.getUid()).collection("watched");
colRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             ArrayList<Movie> tempItems = new ArrayList<>();
             for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                 // Handle data
             }
             } else {
                 Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ",task.getException());
             }
          }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparantly read the documentation about the resource.data wrong. I had to add the author_id field myself. I did not know this, but once I added this it worked like a charm!

Comment: You are not alone.. I thought author_id is a special meta data field on the resource object as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a rule to make sure that the uid of the requesting user matches the `author_id` field of the document:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{User} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but when I do this a user authenticated through the Firebase Android UI get a permission denied on any read.